# prevent 2 users from reading the same id in Real Time Firebase database

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions

I have a real time database of firebase with this structure:

[image]

In my app the user is given a *productId* randomly from *products* and at the same time the *productId* is deleted from *products* and inserted in *consumedProducts*, then he connects to the firestore with this id and makes changes to the object. The problem is that 2 users at the same time can get the same *productId* while in *products* if they access the same page at the same time. Instead I would like that if the first one gets an id , the second one will not get the same one but another one. How could I solve this problem? I have seen the use of transaction https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions but these are used only in case of writing in the same field

Comment: An alternative would be to add `".indexOn": ["claimed"]` to your rules and when a user wants to read a product they query for one product where `"claimed"` is `null` (which is possible in the RTDB) and then try to claim it by writing their user ID to `"<productId>/claimed"` - allow it when `"claimed"` is `null` and if it does have a value that doesn't match the one being attempted, block it signalling to go get a new product to claim. You can then use `"claimed"` to control read/write access to that product.

Comment: Because you make mention of Firestore, take note that it's important to remember that Firestore and the Realtime Database are two different databases and each have their own traits and caveats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to prevent multiple users from reading the same node in the database. If you need that, you'll need to implement your own custom API either on a server you control, or in something like Cloud Functions or Cloud Run.

But since you say you're moving the key from `products` to `consumedProducts`, you may be able to capture that move in a transaction - and prevent multiple users from writing the same key into `consumedProducts` (which they at the same time then also remove from `products`).

You'll need to run a transaction on the `Firebase-root` in your data model in that case, so you may want to consider moving these two nodes under a common ancestor to prevent having contention across your entire database.